# Set dynamic default values of brushed data on x-axis with dates

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

This is a sample of interactive multi-view by using selection

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJ0c.png)

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOOMQAZTlKBGIgAvkuJQ5UNWgDaoTHUFx9AETh1Gj0lAHcaZXo0ABYADlMlZG0Aa30kbTgUJThZJ2UaWTI0UAAPYpAAMxo4QWV9VUxfJUwATxxfdEaEHDZtJBCQaH6O0GU2ZALynHSkBH0mbQYIGDt7ECQSmghyr0wffVWlFvKqmrr0HG0aKCaQVvb9AEcGJFldtRpSVftPbw6QADypG0xGqoUUIHCkRWqDiCQwcBoZCwaAAbPCkql0OlMhDpn0ENtUB4QLJZv8FksVg5+gwRiAysTQC1Mto0AAmcwAdkSciiqC5PxALPSHPMAE5eW8YajbABdNYQGpwKCYHZtf4FRog-oQnJ5ApkIluBkgBXy7K5Nj5QrlRmgU61epqW73f5dHp9PRrY6aSrVJ0XK43CFup4vN50D5fJQbLY7a7JADCbAYbzQAGYlGQrucKv0lbYi-LbEA)

```
"params": [
    {
      "name": "brush",
      "value": {
        "x": [{"year": 2007, "month": 7}, {"year": 2009, "month": 6}]
      },
      "select": {"type": "interval", "encodings": ["x"]}
    }
  ]
```

In the sample, default values of x-axis are set as below:

{"x": [{"year": 2007, "month": 7}, {"year": 2009, "month": 6}]}

I am trying to set "dynamic" default values for the brushed data on the Overview Chart x-axis

I would like to establish a dynamic default date range selection based on a variable date rather than a fixed month.

For instance,

07-2007 -> 180 days prior to the current maximum date

06-2009 -> the current maximum date

Could you please help me with this?